# PostgreSQL jsonb string format

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10

I'm using PostgreSQL jsonb and have the following in my database record:

```
{"tags": "[\"apple\",\" orange\",\" pineapple\",\" fruits\"]",
"filename": "testname.jpg", "title_en": "d1", "title_ja": "1",
"description_en": "d1", "description_ja": "1"}
```

and **both** SELECT statements below retrived **no** results:

```
SELECT "photo"."id", "photo"."datadoc", "photo"."created_timestamp","photo"."modified_timestamp" 
FROM "photo" 
WHERE datadoc @> '{"tags":> ["apple"]}';

SELECT "photo"."id", "photo"."datadoc", "photo"."created_timestamp", "photo"."modified_timestamp" 
FROM "photo" 
WHERE datadoc -> 'tags' ? 'apple';
```

I wonder it is because of the extra backslash added to the json array string, or the SELECT statement is incorrect.

I'm running "PostgreSQL 10.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit" on Windows 10.

PostgreSQL doc is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as any JSON parser is concerned, the value of your `tags` key is a string, not an array.

```
"tags": "[\"apple\",\" orange\",\" pineapple\",\" fruits\"]"
```

The string itself happens to be another JSON document, like the common case in XML where the contents of a string happen to be an XML or HTML document.

```
["apple"," orange"," pineapple"," fruits"]
```

What you need to do is extract that string, then parse it as a new JSON object, and then query that new object.

I can't test it right now, but I think that would look something like this:

```
(datadoc ->> 'tags') ::jsonb ? 'apple'
```

That is, "extract the tags value as `text`, cast that `text` value as `jsonb`, then query that new `jsonb` value.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there i know this is very late answer, but here is the good approach, with data i have.

initital data in db:

```
 "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"test\",\"message\":\"string\",\"image\":\"string\"},\"registration_ids\":[\"s
tring\"],\"isAllUsersNotification\":false}"
```

**to convert it to json**

> select (notificationData #>> '{}')::jsonb from sent_notification

result:

```
 {"data": {"image": "string", "title": "string", "message": "string"}, "registration_ids": ["string"], "isAllUsersNotification": false}
```

getting a **data** object from json

> select (notificationData #>> '{}' )::jsonb -> 'data' from sent_notification;

result:

```
 {"image": "string", "title": "string", "message": "string"}
```

getting a field from above result:

> select (notificationData #>> '{}' )::jsonb -> 'data' ->>'title' from sent_notification;

result:

```
 string
```

performing where operations,

Q: get records where title ='string'

ans:

> select * from sent_notification where (notificationData #>> '{}' )::jsonb -> 'data' ->>'title' ='string'